# C: how does long long have a much larger range than long while using the same 8 bytes of space?

Tags: c, gcc, types

I wrote a short program which uses the `sizeof()` operator understand the space used up by various data types in C with the `gcc` compiler on 64-bit Linux. The output is shown below:

```
A unit "signed char" takes: 1 bytes.
A unit "unsigned char" takes: 1 bytes.
A unit "short signed int" takes: 2 bytes.
A unit "short unsigned int" takes: 2 bytes.
A unit "signed int" takes: 4 bytes.
A unit "unsigned int" takes: 4 bytes.
A unit "long signed int" takes: 8 bytes.
A unit "long unsigned int" takes: 8 bytes.
A unit "signed long long int" takes 8 bytes.
A unit "unsigned long long int" takes 8 bytes.
A unit "float" takes: 4 bytes.
A unit "double" takes: 8 bytes.
A unit "long double" takes: 16 bytes.
A unit "string" takes: 2 bytes.
```

My question pertains to the `long int` and `long long int` data types.

1. If we look at the default `signed` variants of these two, how is `long long` able to have a much higher range (-9,223,372,036,854,775,807 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807) than `long` (-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647) when it uses the same 8 bytes of space per unit? Also,
2. Why use `long` at all, and not just use `long long` all the time?

**EDIT:**
I was looking at the ranges for 32 bit compilation with gcc from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/data-types-in-c/), and not 64 bit, which caused the confusion. Modified my code to include the ranges in the output, along with the sizes, using the LIMIT MACROS defined in `limits.h`. The corrected output now reads:

```
Unit "signed char" -> 1 bytes -> range: -128 - +127.
Unit "unsigned char" -> 1 bytes -> range: 0 - 255.


Unit "short signed int" -> 2 bytes -> range: -32768 - +32767.
Unit "short unsigned int" -> 2 bytes -> range: 0 - 65535.

Unit "signed int" -> 4 bytes -> range: -2147483648 - +2147483647.
Unit "unsigned int" -> 4 bytes -> range 0 - 4294967295.

Unit "long signed int" -> 8 bytes -> range: -9223372036854775808 - +9223372036854775807.
Unit "long unsigned int" -> 8 bytes -> range 0 - 18446744073709551615.

Unit "signed long long int" -> 8 bytes -> range -9223372036854775808 - +9223372036854775807.
Unit "unsigned long long int" -> 8 bytes -> range 0 - 18446744073709551615.


Unit "float" -> 4 bytes.
Unit "double" -> 8 bytes.
Unit "long double" -> 16 bytes.
Unit "string" -> 2 bytes.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The range of `long` and `long long` on your system is the same: -2<sup>63</sup> to 2<sup>63</sup>-1. You can check by printing out the values of [`LONG_MIN` and `LONG_MAX`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits#Limits_of_integer_types). When two types have the same range, they usually have the same size. (This property is not guaranteed by the C language, but platforms where this is not the case are very unusual.)

The range of types depends on the platform. The *portable* range of `long` is -2<sup>31</sup>+1 to 2<sup>31</sup>-1. The portable range of `long long` is -2<sup>63</sup>+1 to 2<sup>63</sup>-1. You should use `long` if you need more than the portable range of `int` (which is -2<sup>15</sup>+1 to 2<sup>15</sup>-1) but not more than the portable range of `long`. More practically, most of the time, you would use `long` when you need to use a library that manipulates values of type `long`.

Among common platforms, `long` is typically the size of a machine register (32 bits on a 32-bit machine, 64 bits on a 64-bit machine) (but it has to be two (or more) registers on a 16-bit machine). There is one notable exception: on 64-bit Windows, the size of `long` is still 32 bits as on 32-bit Windows.

Comment: thanks, modified my code to use the various LIMIT MACRO EXANSIONS.

Answer (score 3):

Question 1 contains an error. The range (-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647) applies to a 4-byte signed value - in your case a `signed int`, not a `signed long`. On your system a `long` will have just as wide a range as a `long long`, so there is no real need for you to use `long long`. But on other systems, the sizes are likely to be different, and the differences might matter to you.

Answer (score 1):

According to your second question `long` is a bit dangerous type to use because it depends on the compiler. `long` can take 4 or 8 bytes

Answer (score 1):

short answer is no
you can't have more range in 8 bytes

if you familiar to microcontrollers or difference between 32bit systems and 64bit systems

you fill find out "int" in 8bit system is just 2 byte but "int" in 32 bit system is 4 byte
that's why we usually int32_t except "int"

because we wanna sure about valid range of that we can store in variable

so long in 32bit system is just 8 byte
and that long in 8bit system is 32 byte
and so on
long long in 64bit system is 128byte

Answer (score 1):

The size of each char, short, int, long, and long long are chosen by the compiler authors, they are free to choose independent of processor or operating system (the language has some rules but leaves freedom).  You simply cannot make assumptions, you have to test as you have done here, per compiler per target os per target processor.  Thus the stdint.h solution which is extremely specific to the compiler not C library not target OS, etc. But is there to allow you to specify an 8, 16, 32, ... bit variable.  If your paths are off and the wrong stdint.h is used when building it creates a huge mess if you relied on those sizes and you have different tools installed with different choices.

So you will find situations where short and int are the same size or int and long are the same size or long and long long are the same size.  It is just how the language works and for a specific compiler for a specific target/system where two types are the same size, and you choose not to use stdint.h then your question is valid.  And the answer is there is no right answer, it is the application programmers personal choice for whatever reason.  You may choose int instead of long if the same size so your printf can use %u instead of %lu, whatever you choose is right for you.

Most people will say it is the wrong answer to use int or long or long long instead use uint32_t, uint64_t, etc.

Answer (score 0):

C does not specify the sizes of arithmetic types, it only specifies the *minimum range of values* they must be able to represent with a *minimum precision*; the implementation may choose to use a wider range, but not a narrower one.

So per the language definition, a signed `long` must be able to represent values in *at least* the range `[-(231-1)...231-1]`<sup>1</sup>, which implies a size of *at least* 32 bits.  However, on your particular implementation, they decided to support a wider range for `long`.

---

1. C neither assumes nor requires two’s complement representation for signed integer values.